# How to position text to be beside navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a webpage. Right now my navigation bars and header look fine but I'm stumped with the body text. I Was wondering how do you  make my paragraphs float to the right of my navigation bar. Right now their stuck below it. What CSS code would I use to make it float to the right?

this is what it looks like so far https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmroX.png ...and below this is  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvVqO.png which i want beside the navi bar

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
 <head>
<!-- Author: Abdullahi Jama 0003 -->
   <title>Cycling Tours</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="printstyles.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aboutus.css" >
 </head>

 <body>

<header>
    <a href="about_us.html"><img src="images/bicycle_axle_sm.jpg" alt="This is a picture of a axle"></a>
    <h1>Cycling Tours</h1>
</header>

<div class="navmenu">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">AboutUs</a></li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#">AskUs</a></li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#">Destinations</a></li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#">Seminars</a></li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#">Trip Prep</a></li>
        <hr>


    </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
 <div class="paragraph">
<h2>About Us</h2> 

    <p>Cycling Tours began when Bill Randolf and three of his friends     from high school began to cycle regularly every weekend. 
    Their routine cycling evolved into frequent cycling trips and they   cultivated a following. Before they knew it, other friends and family members asked to join them in their trips.</p>
    <div id="dust_jpeg">
    <img id="dustimage" src="images/dust.jpg" alt="Picutre of Dust">
    </div>
    <p>Cyclists are enthusiastic and very health and environmentally conscious. For this reason, all of our trips include vegan options for meals, recycled paper food serving utensils, 
    and hybrid vehicles to escort the cyclists.</p>

    <p>Our trips are suitable for solo cyclists, couples, friends, and families. We provide camping accommodation for off-road cycling trips, and shared accommodations for couples, friends and families. If you are travelling solo, we can match you with someone for shared accommodations. 
    You can also pay the single-supplement if you wish to have a room of your own.</p>

    <p>After you've completed one trip with us, we're sure you'll want to do more. Over 80% of our customers have been on at least one prior trip with us. 
    We're always looking for new ideas for trips, so please let us know if you have any ideas!</p>

</div>

    <p id="bicycleimage"><img src="images/bicycles_sm.jpg" alt="An image of some bikes."><p>

    <hr>

    <p id="bottom_footer"><strong>Cycling Tours * P.O. Box 4455 * Brantford, ON * NET 2J0</strong><p>   
</body>
</html>




<style type ="text/css">

   header h1 {
           display: inline;
           font-size: 45px;
           font-family: arial;  
           vertical-align: 90%;
           margin: 30px;
   }

   header {
           background-color: #bbccdd;
           padding-bottom: 0px;
           height: 121px;
   }

   .navmenu{
           background-color: #bbccdd;
           width: 8.8%;
           height: 580px;
           display:inline-block;
   }
   .navmenu hr {
           border: 1px solid grey;
   }
   .navmenu ul {
           margin-top: 0;
           padding-left: 2px;
           display:inline-block;
   }
   .navmenu li {
           height: 35px;
           padding-top: 30px;
           padding-left: 10px;
           font-family: arial;
           color: grey;
           display:inline-block;

   }    
   .navmenu li a {
           color: #888888;
           text-decoration: none;
           font-weight: bold;

   }
   .navmenu a:link {
           color: #888888;
   }
   .paragraph {
           width: 60%;
           margin-left: 10%;
           border-top: 0;
   }

</style>
```

Comment: Hey, why don't use Table?

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of a beginner to this, how would i do that? btw check the edit i added a picture so you can visualize my problem.

Comment: In regards to the first comment, using tables for non-tabular data is very bad practice in today's standards.

Answer (score 0):

Float the sidebar to the left

```
.navmenu {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your html structure little bit. Please have a look...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Author: Abdullahi Jama 0003 -->
  <title>Cycling Tours</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="printstyles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aboutus.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <a href="about_us.html">
      <img src="images/bicycle_axle_sm.jpg" alt="This is a picture of a axle">
    </a>
    <h1>Cycling Tours</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="navmenu">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">AboutUs</a>
        </li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#">AskUs</a>
        </li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#">Destinations</a>
        </li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
        </li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a>
        </li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#">Seminars</a>
        </li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#">Trip Prep</a>
        </li>
        <hr>


      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraph">
    <h2>About Us</h2> 

    <p>Cycling Tours began when Bill Randolf and three of his friends from high school began to cycle regularly every weekend. Their routine cycling evolved into frequent cycling trips and they cultivated a following. Before they knew it, other friends and
      family members asked to join them in their trips.</p>
    <div id="dust_jpeg">
      <img id="dustimage" src="images/dust.jpg" alt="Picutre of Dust">
    </div>
    <p>Cyclists are enthusiastic and very health and environmentally conscious. For this reason, all of our trips include vegan options for meals, recycled paper food serving utensils, and hybrid vehicles to escort the cyclists.</p>

    <p>Our trips are suitable for solo cyclists, couples, friends, and families. We provide camping accommodation for off-road cycling trips, and shared accommodations for couples, friends and families. If you are travelling solo, we can match you with someone
      for shared accommodations. You can also pay the single-supplement if you wish to have a room of your own.</p>

    <p>After you've completed one trip with us, we're sure you'll want to do more. Over 80% of our customers have been on at least one prior trip with us. We're always looking for new ideas for trips, so please let us know if you have any ideas!</p>
    <p id="bicycleimage">
      <img src="images/bicycles_sm.jpg" alt="An image of some bikes.">
      <p>

        <hr>

        <p id="bottom_footer"><strong>Cycling Tours * P.O. Box 4455 * Brantford, ON * NET 2J0</strong>
          <p>
  </div>





</body>

</html>




<style type="text/css">
  header h1 {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family: arial;
    vertical-align: 90%;
    margin: 30px;
  }
  header {
    background-color: #bbccdd;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    height: 121px;
  }
  .navmenu {
    float: left;
    background-color: #bbccdd;
    min-width: 8.8%;
    height: 580px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navmenu hr {
    border: 1px solid grey;
  }
  .navmenu ul {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navmenu li {
    height: 35px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-family: arial;
    color: grey;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navmenu li a {
    color: #888888;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .navmenu a:link {
    color: #888888;
  }
  .paragraph {
    width: 90.2%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    border-top: 0;
  }
</style>
```